# Webpack using any other js with bundle js without using require or dependency approach

Tags: javascript, html, webpack

I am learning webpack but i m confused that if I bundle my all javascript, then if its possible to include any other js after bundle js made through webpack in html, without using require or dependency approach.
Thanks-

Comment: Yes, you can do, and unless you are using some specific loader webpack will not touch any script tag in your html file (including the tag you need to include your bundle)

Comment: Thanks I'll try once...also..